# One button is white until cursor is over it. All other buttons are blue

Tags: html, angular

In an Angular HTML page I have then following button:

```
<button (click)="remove(tempCartItem)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-2">Remove</button>
```

In my browser it is white and changes to blue when the cursor is over it.

Other buttons in my application with the same `class` property are always blue. Why would this one button be different and how do I fix this?

**Additional info:**

This button is in a table. My styles.css contains the following:

```css
table.table.table-bordered{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#fff
}
```

If I update `background:#fff` to `background:#000` the button is black until I hover the cursor over it. Once I do the button turns to the correct blue colour.

Comment: check the button's parents and see if there is a nested button selector that changes the colour

Comment: Check the component style file, the `class` may overridden there.

Comment: @Amer Thanks. I cehcked cart-details.component.css. The file is empty. @RameshReddy, what do you mean by `see if there is a nested button selector that changes the colour`? how do I do that?